# Text area/input hard to select/edit for some cells (tabs/empty spaces?)

Tags: html, jquery, css

So I have Create & an Update view with Django. Both use the same template for the form. (It doesn't *seem* to be a Django problem perse, but in case it turns out relevant...)

With the  CreateView, I can easily click into a textarea widget and edit its value. With the UpdateView however, I seem to need to use a bunch of click before somehow I manage to edit the content of the area. I have compared the html/css in both cases & they are exactly the same.

Upon further inspection, it seems that the imported data contains tabs in some empty fields (hence why it only appends in the UpdateView). So the issue appears to be that when I click anywhere in the input/textarea, the tabs make it hard to actually focus/select the cell. That may be why random clicks (or double-clicks to select the tab?) appear to allow me to edit properly.

I'm unsure if the tabs originate from the source data somehow, or just got added along the way. Of course I'll probably figure out a way to clean out that data.

Is there a quick css/jquery fix for this? Some sort of $('input').on("click"...) handler I could use? Of course one option would be to clean up the source data. However if for whatever reason they've been living fine with those in their previous system, I might just leave it & go for a quick fix, should one exists.

Something like this:

```
<textarea name="descfr2" cols="40" rows="10" maxlength="60" id="id_descfr2">                                                            </textarea>
```

https://codepen.io/logikonabstractions/pen/GRWPROO

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `focus()` method from jquery (https://api.jquery.com/focus/).

Try to add the event on your cells so that the input inside became focused on click:

```
$('.cells').click(function(){
    $(this).find('input').focus();
}
```

I would do something like that (if you can select all your cells with some class attributes)